# wordpress can not load resources and not logged in into dashboard

Tags: php, css, wordpress, admin

I'm new in wordpress also now I'm admin of this website http://ksu1953.org but ther's have some probles the site can not load css resources and I can not log in to the dashboard [admin login](http://ksu1958.org/wp-admin) please how i can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Look where WP is looking for your content files - http://joxi.ru/vAWzE4qt1x96P2 , http://joxi.ru/ZrJzxNRt95XRMr Now look when you remove it from the URL all is good files are loaded - http://joxi.ru/vAWzE4qt1x9aP2 You have done something so WP is looking inside this folder. A bit hard to say where and what causes this problem without getting some more information about what have been done on the page ...